# Macros for Vlookup using Column Header

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I have 2 Worksheets. I will have a macro to do the Vlookup in Sheet1. Sheet2 will be the data stored. However the column of the data won't be same for each term, therefore I will have to check the column name.

This is Sheet 1. I will enter the 'Member ID' Then do Vlookup to sheet 2 to get 'Member Name' & 'Remarks'.

[image]

This is Sheet 2, where all the data are stored.

[image]

This is the Vlookup codes.

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
.Range("G2:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet2!C[-3]:C[-2],2,FALSE)"
End With
With Sheets("Sheet1")
.Range("H2:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],Sheet2!C[-4]:C,5,FALSE)"
End With
```

I trying to Vlookup by searching for the Column header. But I not sure how to I do it.

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
' Map Account name
Rows("1:1").Select
Set cell = Selection.Find(What:="Member ID", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If cell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Column 'Member ID' could not be found.", vbCritical, "No such column"
    Cancel = True
Else
    'Vlookup here
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for VBA here! you can do this with formula all along. Two options:

**1. Use INDEX/MATCH**

Use the following formula in G2: `=INDEX(Sheet2!E:E,MATCH(F2,Sheet2!D:D,0)`. Replace the `E:E`with `H:H` in the next column.

you can now shift the order of the columns ins sheet 2 to your liking.

**2. Use VLOOKUP and MATCH**

In case you don't know the order up front, you can also just find the column number first - and then build the VLOOKUP:

- In Sheet1, add a row above the header. Place the following formula in F1 (and copy to H1): `=MATCH(F2,Sheet2!1:1,0)`. This will return the column number for each header.
- Now place the following formula in G3 and copy it down and right to column H: `=VLOOKUP($F3,Sheet2!$D:$Z,G$1-F$1+1,0)`

Hope that help!

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping :) I tried the first and second formula, it works but the third formula `=VLOOKUP($H3,Sheet2!$H:$Z,G$1-H$1,0)` I got _#VALUE!_. I tried it `=VLOOKUP($F3,Sheet2!$H:$Z,G$1-H$1,0)` and got _#NA_. For the second part, why is it Sheet2!$H:$Z?

Comment: Sorry, my bad - it must be `=VLOOKUP($F3,Sheet2!$D:$Z,G$1-F$1,0)` - i corrected the answer. The `$Z` is just in case your table has many columns...

Comment: because g1-f1 is the number of columns between the ID column and the column you want to return - i.e. it is the value for the third parameter of VLOOKUP.

Comment: Oh then is `=VLOOKUP(F3,Sheet2!$D:$Z,G$1-F$1,FALSE)` the same as `=VLOOKUP(F3,Sheet2!$D:$Z,F1:G1,FALSE)`?

Comment: not really. it is the same as `=VLOOKUP(F3,Sheet2!$D:$Z,5-4,FALSE)` (now i realize that it must be `G$1-F$1+1`!!!) - if you followed the first bullet in instruction!

Comment: Oh, no wonder. Thanks a lot! :) Option 2 works :) But what if I change the question a little. I will enter the 'Member Name' instead of Member ID' Then do Index Match to sheet 2 to get 'Member ID' can it work for option 2? I got this `=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,G1)` at F3.